# How to change Form colors dynamically with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app and I'm trying to change the form borders live when the user enters some string to the textbox.

```
<input type="url" name="site" class="form-control" ng-model="site" required maxlength="255">
```

Basically I'm using ngMessages to validate the form.

So when the form is VALID I get `ng-valid` as a class to the input field.

When the form is INVALID I get `ng-invalid` as a class to the input field.

Now my idea was to simply assign some CSS styling to these selectors and it will change the border's color. However it didn't!

```
.form-control.ng-valid, .form-control.ng-valid:focus {
    border-color: green;
};

.form-control.ng-invalid.ng-dirty, .form-control.ng-invalid.ng-dirty:focus {
    border-color: red;
};
```

When I run the code, only the GREEN showed up (when it was valid) and the red didn't (while it should have been red).

So it's like the 2nd CSS rule isn't even being inspected. If I change up the order, then RED shows up and green doesn't.

What could be the issue here? I don't really understand why could such thing happen.

Comment: Have you tried the separate classes, like this:
.form-control.ng-invalid,
.form-control.ng-dirty, 
.form-control.ng-invalid:focus,
.form-control.ng-dirty:focus { ... }

Comment: Have you tried removing .ng-dirty and just having .form-control.ng-invalid, .form-control.ng-invalid:focus { ... }

Comment: @Toastrackenigma Yes tried, but the same results.